# How to throw NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android

I am creating some classes that do not implement threading logic but need to be used off the main thread, so I want to throw NetworkOnMainThreadException (or a similar one for DB operations) in their constructors.
How do I do that? How do Android do that, can I find it somewhere in the source code?

Comment: do you see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: This link is about how to avoid it, I dont want to avoid it but throw it

Comment: oh sorry i don't understand your question, but i read that a network connection is impossible on main thread no ?

Comment: @Paul he wants to throw that exception if the runs on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check the current's thread looper. E.g.

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   throw new NetworkOnMainThreadException();
}
```

I would avoid it anyway. If I were in you I would document the method/class to clarify it has to be executed on an asynchronously

Comment: I used to name these classes by appending "Synchronous" at the end of the name but I think it's ugly.

Comment: then, probably you should thrown your custom exception